# Joining in SQL with Timestamp Intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following tables.

```
Table A

Id   Paket    Starttime                Endtime
8    4714     2019-05-23 13:28:28.000  2019-05-23 13:28:31.000
7    4713     2019-05-23 13:28:10.000  2019-05-23 13:28:28.000
6    4712     2019-05-23 13:27:57.000  2019-05-23 13:28:10.000
5    4711     2019-05-23 13:27:40.000  2019-05-23 13:27:57.000
```

```
Table B

Timestamp                  Bla
2019-05-23 13:28:26.000    A
2019-05-23 13:28:27.000    A
2019-05-23 13:28:28.000    A
2019-05-23 13:28:29.000    B
2019-05-23 13:28:30.000    B
2019-05-23 13:28:31.000    B
2019-05-23 13:28:32.000    B
2019-05-23 13:28:33.000    B
```

I would like to have the following result.

```
Result

Timestamp                  Bla    Paket
2019-05-23 13:28:26.000    A      4713
2019-05-23 13:28:27.000    A      4713
2019-05-23 13:28:28.000    A      4714
2019-05-23 13:28:29.000    B      4714
2019-05-23 13:28:30.000    B      4714
```

Some things to note:

- In `Table A`, the start time of one paket is the same as the end time of its predecessor.
- In `Table A` I don't really care if the intervals are half-open on one side or the other. For example, the time `2019-05-23 13:28:28.000` may belong to either Paket 4713 or 4714 (but not both). Either interpretation is fine. In `Result`, I have written that `2019-05-23 13:28:28.000` belongs to 4714, but I may as well have written 4713 (and then added one more line for `2019-05-23 13:28:31.000`).
- In `Result` there may be fewer lines than in `Table B`, because the last lines of `Table B` may not fall into any of the Start-Endtime Intervals from `Table A`.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

How would a SQL look like to join Tables A and B to get the desired result?
Appreciate any of your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `join`:

```
select b.*, a.paket
from b join
     a
     on b.timestamp >= a.starttime and
        b.timestamp < a.endtime;
```